# saving card information to stripe and charge customer later

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I want my customers to fill the cc information through stripe without charging them initially but i would manually charge them later accordingly to the service i provide them.  it

is it possible to simply save their card information on the stripe itself so i could manually go and charge them through stripe internally? i am new to stripe so i don't understand it all.

i came acrossed this

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                        'amount' => $request->amount * 100,
                        'currency' => 'usd',
                        'receipt_email' => $request->email,
                        'payment_method_types' => ["card"],
                        'setup_future_usage' => 'off_session'
                        )
                    ]);
```

but its always says **The PaymentIntent requires a payment method** which i don't seem to understand and don't see option of manually charging them after running PaymentIntent.

plus i am using one field to collect the cc information on which it collects cc number, month, expiry date and cvc which is provided from stripe website, i am not collecting them individually.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe has [documentation about saving payment information for future use](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) that covers this scenario.

For PHP, the steps would basically be:

1. Create a Customer
2. Create a Setup Intent that specifies that Customer
3. Collect payment details
4. Confirm the Setup Intent

That will create a Payment Method and attach it to the Customer.  You can then use that Customer/Payment Method combination later to create a Payment Intent and collect a payment.